# Linux find-command with regex and write in a file working strange

Tags: regex, linux, terminal, find

So I have a folder with .wav files that look like this:

> afr_(4 digits)_(random digits).wav

I want to create a list with all files that start with for example afr_0184_ and afr_1919_ and I use this linux command line

> find /directory/  -name
> "arf_0184_*.wav" -o -name "afr_1919_*.wav" > train.list

For some reason the list only has afr_1919_ files in it as if it overwrites the afr_0184_ that are found before them.

I also tried this

> find /directory/ -name 'afr_(0184|1919)_*.wav' > train.list

but the list is empty in this case.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `"arf_0184_*.wav"`?

Comment: It would only give me afr_0184_ items, but I also want afr_1919 in my list.

Comment: I mean is that `arf` a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
find /directory/ -regextype posix-egrep -regex '.*/afr_(0184|1919)_[0-9]*\.wav' > train.list
```

To match any 4 digit variations instead of the two 'hardcoded' values, use

```
'.*/afr_[0-9]{4}_[0-9]*\.wav'
```

Using `-name`, you can only search with a glob wildcard pattern, you need `-regex`.

With `-regextype posix-egrep`, you can use alternation and unescaped capturing parentheses. `[0-9]*` match any zero or more digits (replace `*` with `+` to match one or more).

The `.*/` is added because the regex should match the whole path string.

Comment: Thank you. It works now, but do you know if I can sort the items in train.list somehow? And why do you type the '\' after [0-9]*?

Comment: @PetarYakov That is so evident to me I have not decided to include it into the answer: `.` matches any char, `\.` matches a literal dot. To sort, you may pipe the `find` results into `sort`, I believe.

Comment: A bit late, but the way to sort the items is to type '| sort -n' before the '>' in the find command. '-n' is for ascending order and '-nr' is for descending. Or you could use 'sort -o file file' to sort the file after it was created.